# After upgrading from Kotlin 1.8.0 to 1.8.20/21 Gradle sync fails with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am working on a big project that uses Kotlin and a lot of other dependencies.
All Kotlin dependencies are using exactly the same version (like ext.version.kotlin)

Once I update kotlin version from 1.8.0 to 1.8.20 or 1.8.21 (and all of Kotlin dependencies as well) Gradle sync fails on an exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/{user}/StudioProjects/{project}/build.gradle' line: 75

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project '{project}'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinCompilerPluginSupportPlugin


Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinCompilerPluginSupportPlugin
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2053)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3966)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3989)
        at build_9p9pcmezmt1efrj5n8osntc17$_run_closure1$_closure6.doCall(/Users/{user}/StudioProjects/{project}/build.gradle:75)
```

So it fails on line `build_9p9pcmezmt1efrj5n8osntc17$_run_closure1$_closure6.doCall(/Users/{user}/StudioProjects/{project}/build.gradle:75)`

which contains:

`if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("{any plugin name}")) {`

Previously this code was working perfectly fine. The only change I made is kotlin version upgrade.

Versions:
AGP: 7.4.0
Gradle: 7.6
Android Studio: electic eel
Kotlin: 1.8.21

Trying to upgrade AGP and Gradle to latest versions, didn't change anything

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? Facing the same issue.